# PHP How to know if a date is "taken" in calendar

Tags: php

In my app, the users are able to create event and other users can join them.

To have a global view of this, I wanted to make a calendar that will enable the user to see the details of the event (with a :hover or something) but I am stuck at some point.

Here is my [calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPHF4.png), it is working fine but my problem is that I am not dealing with the date the same way in my database and ine my calendar function.

I am making my calendar using `date('w')` and `date('n')` to respectively have the weeks and the months but in my database my variable `$date_f` is a "date" type in YYYY-MM-DD format.

I am kinda confused because I don't really know how to proceed.
I guess I will have to separate the month/year/day in my `$date_f` variable and then when it is corresponding to a day in my loop changing the class of the `<td>` to color it or something.

Do you guys have any advices on how to do this effectively ?

It may not be necessary but here is a part of my PHP code where the calendar is made :

```
// Making of the calendar

for ($l = 0 ; $l < 6 ; $l++){ // 6 lign calendar 
    echo '<tr class="days">';
    for ($i = 0 ; $i < 7 ; $i++){ // 7 days of the week

        // $sem = array(6,0,1,2,3,4,5);
        // $t = mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1, $y); // Basically $m and $y are the current month/year
        $w = $sem[(int)date('w',$t)]; // Days of the week to proceed with 
        $m2 = (int)date('n',$t); // Month to begin with
        if (($w == $i) && ($m2 == $m)){ // Checking if the day/months are corresponding

            echo '<td>'.date('j',$t).'</td>'; // Showing the day of the month
            $t += 86400; // Going to the next day
        }
        else{
            echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>'; // Empty 
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

So far I tried to fetch all of my `$date_f` into an object to work with it but I am stuck there :

```
$reqDate = $bdd->query('SELECT date_f FROM formation');
$result = $reqDate->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

How can I make it so for each `$date_f` in my database the days of my calendar will be in a different color ?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is take the database results as an array and see if the date on the calendar matches any of the values in the array.

So if `$result` contains an array of dates, you can replace this:

```
echo '<td>'.date('j',$t).'</td>';
```

with this:

```
echo '<td';
if(in_array(date('Y-m-d',$t), $result))
   echo ' style="color:red;"';
echo '>'.date('j',$t).'</td>';
```

Comment: I am trying to make it work but I have got trouble taking my database into an array. I tried the following : `$reqDate = $bdd->query('SELECT date_f FROM formation');`  `$result = [];`  `while ($donnees = $reqDate->fetch()){array_push($result,$donnees['date_f']); }`  And my $result is the following array : `Array ( [0] => 2019-02-02 [1] => 2020-02-02 [2] => 2019-01-01 [3] => 2020-04-06 [4] => 2020-04-08 [5] => 2019-09-21 [6] => 2019-07-05 [7] => 2020-05-03 [8] => 2019-03-02 [9] => 2019-01-03 )` But I am still getting the error `in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given`

Comment: I believe the $result should be an array that you can just pass to in_array() in your original example. `$reqDate = $bdd->query('SELECT date_f FROM formation');
$result = $reqDate->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);` If this doesn't work, what happens if you `print_r($result);` right below the following code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to search the database for any `date_f` containing the current date, before outputting your `<td>`

You can then use a CSS class to highlight those particular dates.

```php
// Find any date_f matching the current date
$reqDate = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM formation WHERE date_f = '" . date( 'Y-m-d', $t ) . "'" );
$result = $reqDate->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

// $result should be an array, so find out if it contains any results
if ( is_array( $result ) && count( $result ) )
{
  // date is taken - add class to <td>
  $td_class = 'taken';
}
else
{
  // date not taken - don't add a class to <td>
  $td_class = '';
}

echo '<td class="' . $td_class . '">'.date('j',$t).'</td>'; // Showing the day of the month
```

CSS

```css
td.taken { background: #f00; }
```

N.B. you should really be using prepared statements for the `$bdd->query()` but that's outside of the scope of the question ;)

Comment: This works, but making a database call for each day is inefficient.

Comment: @chris-bartow Good point. Upvoted your answer as the array method should improve efficiency.